# Export a plot from R and increase size?

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I am using R studio and exporting my plots with it. They look fine at smaller resolutions but when I make them larger for a word doc they become hard to read and don't look as 'crisp'.

Is there a better way to be exporting them that so when I make them larger they still look good ?

thanks

Comment: I think the answer to your question depends, in part, on which format you're using for your saved plots. Could you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to export a `png` file with different width/height

```
lm.SR <- lm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)

library(grDevices)
png(file="myplot.png", width=1024, height=768)
plot(lm.SR, 1)
dev.off()

png(file="myplot2.png", width=2048, height=1536)
plot(lm.SR, 1)
dev.off()
```

Files will be stored in your current working directory

```
getwd()
```